# A charset issue about an ASCII experiment I'm doing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to develop a new kind of JavaScript compressor that works on binary, unlike regular minifiers (like Closure Compiler) or dictionnary-based packers (like JScrush).

Here's the idea:

I want to compress the JS code `alert(123)`.

-The compressor takes each character and converts it from ASCII to binary:

```
01100001 01101100 01100101 01110010 01110100 00101000 00110001 00110010 00110011 00101001
```

-Then, it removes the higher bit of each character, because it's always 0 in ASCII

```
1100001 1101100 1100101 1110010 1110100 0101000 0110001 0110010 0110011
```

-Then, it makes a long string with the remaining bits

```
"110000111011001100101111001011101000101000011000101100100110011"
```

-Then, it cuts this string in blocks of 8 bits

```
11000011 10110011 00101111 00101110 10001010 00011000 10110010 01100110
```

-Then, it convert each block in a 8-bit character

```
Ã³/.²f
```

The decoder will only have to do the opposite to get the original JS back.

So I made this encoder and this decoder in JavaScript, and it works like a charm:

http://xem.github.io/JSciissors/

If you put 11k characters on top, you get 10k characters at the bottom, and if you execute the bottom code, it works. Cool!

But, if you save the encoded script in a text file, there's a problem:

-If you save it in UTF-8, every non-ASCII character will be stored on 2 bytes, and the compressed file will be larger than the original file.

-If you save it in latin-1 (a.k.a iso-8859-1), then the file size is OK (each character will fit in one byte), but when you execute it, it doesn't work, because the decoding is not accurate anymore:

```
alers�123)
```

I'm surprised by this result because the UTF8's first 256 code points match the Latin-1 first 256 code points.

There's the same problem if you save it in ANSI (a.k.a windows-1252).

Can someone please explain me what happens here, why it doesn't work as expected, and if there is a solution?

Thanks a lot!

PS: here's my encoder and decoder in JS (but I think the problem is not really in the JS, it's in the transcoding...)

```
// Encoder
// @param d: original JS code
function e(d,b,f,c,a){b=a="";for(f in d+=";")c=d.charCodeAt(f),a+=(1e6+c.toString(2)).slice(-7);for(;7<a.length;)c=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a.substring(0,8),2)),b+=c,a=a.slice(8);return b}

// Decoder:
a='(encoded JS code)';b=c='';for(i=0;(original JS length)>i;i++)b+=(1e7+a.charCodeAt(i).toString(2)).slice(-8),c+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b.substr(i*7,7),2));eval(c)
```

Comment: No general-purpose compressor can assume the input is ASCII, so your first step (removing the high-order bit)  won't work. UTF-8 uses all eight bits, not just the lower seven: If your UTF-8 file contains a BOM or any of the thousands of characters that require high-order bits in UTF-8, it'll fail.

Comment: Indeed, my compressor assumes that the input is only ASCII. And it works as long as we respect this rule. (but it's not hard to have only ASCII chars in a JS file, as non-ASCII chars can be escaped.). UTF-8's first 127 characters match the 127 ASCII chars.

Comment: The encoded script is not text, so why would you expect a text editor to handle it correctly?

Comment: @Eric: I'd misread that. Yes, indeed! Heaven only knows what the editor will make of the data, it won't look like text...

Comment: well, charsets like latin-1 and ANSI have code points that correspond to each possible byte, from 0x00 to 0xFF, so any binary code can have a valid text representation, based on one of these charsets. No?

Comment: @xem: You've said when you save the file as UTF-8 you get a problem. I'm not surprised, UTF-8 is not a one-to-one correlation of bytes to characters. Some bytes introduce byte *series*. An editor will presumably try to fix broken ones, if it thinks the file it's reading is UTF-8 or if you ask it to write the file out as UTF-8. Basically, as soon as something else is processing the file, you're toast.

Comment: Yeah but I'm sure I'm not very far from the goal... the problem only appears on a few characters, so I think it's just a transcoding issue of some control characters which are different in utf-8 and in latin1 and in ANSI... http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html

Comment: The “decoder” does not work and is not even proper code. Fixed to real code and set to use the length of the coded string instead of the odd constant 3, it works. Such “compression” is rather uninteresting, but there isn’t even any well-formulated technical question about it. There is probably something wrong in the code (that was not disclosed) for reading various types of input.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela indeed, my bad, the "3" was wrong, but on the "official" page, the constant is well replaced by the input length: http://xem.github.io/JSciissors/

Comment: @xem Right on! Finally someone is trying something not out-of-the-box creative and with a theory behind. I wish there was more posts like yours.

Comment: Do not do this. Just compress (gzip) your plain js file when serving it. This would be much more performant and efficient than a custom js en/decoding. As an experiment, cool, but you should not use this in production.

Comment: @Bergi My goal is to make raw JS files lighter, like JScrush but with a different technique. It could be useful for code golfing competitions where Gzip is not allowed (like JS1K). Moreover, JSciissors + gzip is lighter than gzip alone!

Comment: @Lex Podgorny thanks! I just wish someone will help me with this encoding issue eventually ^^ I have other experimental projects on my github account (github.com/xem) ;)

Comment: @xem: Windows 1252 doesn't have anything at, for example, 0x81 and 0x90. Also, control codes used by ISO 8859-1 for 0x80-0x9F are very fragile. Also, your encoding will result with control codes from 0x00 to 0x1F. Your text editor will mess up line endings, among other things.